# How to use transltr api

Tags: php, api, xampp, localhost

How can I call [transltr api](http://www.transltr.org/Developers) from my localhost using php? I have zero knowledge in calling api and what to type in the php file. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php cUrl library must be loaded and enabled.
You can check this using phpinfo file.

To use API, you can try code below.

```
<?php
$params = array('text'=>'something',  'from'=>'en', 'to'=>'de');
$data_string = json_encode($params);

$ch = curl_init('http://www.transltr.org/api/translate');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$result){
die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}

echo $result;

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curl_exec function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) from CURL extension.
In the most simple form it looks like:

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Now `$result` holds what you need.

Comment: Is this the basic for calling api?